# How to use camera in Google VR SDK 1.50 for Unity?

Tags: unity, android, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I have looked at many tutorials on making an Android app for Google Cardboard in Unity, but all of them were for older versions of the GVR SDK. How do I simply add a stereo camera in version 1.50 (with Unity 5.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With previous versions on Google VR SDK, you added a prefab called `GvrViewerMain` to the scene to get a stereoscopic camera. The `GvrEditorEmulator` prefab has replaced `GvrViewerMain` in 1.50+.

The preview in Unity will *not* appear as stereoscopic, but it will be stereoscopic when built for Android.

Check out the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/release-notes#google_vr_sdk_for_unity_v150_may_2017) for Google VR SDK 1.50 for more details.